# Python - Using a variable as part of string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to be able to use a int variable instead of the number (5) used in the code below. I hope there is a way or else I will have to put my code within **if** blocks which I am trying to avoid if possible (I don't want it to go through a condition everytime in my loop).

```
my_array[1, 0] = '{0:.5f}'.format(a)
```

Is there a way for me to write the code below using a variable like:

```
x = 5
my_array[1, 0] = '{0:.xf}'.format(a)
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: the output is tricky and works without an issue. I have the code running without a problem. The question is regarding using a variable inside the {} brackets. The reason is when a certian condition matches I have to put a lot of different lines within if/elif statements. And I want to avoid that. I would rather assign a variable above this code and not have to change the lines here. I know it sound a bit confuing. I'm just trying to avoid unneeded if statements that are in loops that go over hundreds of times.

Comment: for example I see but yet haven't learned the % sign in code.. like %x... I doubt that's how it works but maybe there is a way like it that allows me to use the variable within the brackets before .format()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course there is:

```
x = 5
a = '{1:.{0}f}'.format(x, 1.12345111)
print(a)  # -> 1.12345
```

If you do not want to specify the positions (`0` & `1`), you just have to **invert** your input:

```
a = '{:.{}f}'.format(1.12345111, x)
#                    ^ the float that is to be formatted goes first
```

That is because the **first argument** to `format()` goes to the
**first (outermost) bracket** of the string.

As a result, the following **fails**:

```
a = '{:.{}f}'.format(x, 1.12345111)
```

since `{:1.12345111f}` is invalid.

---

Other examples of formatting you might find interesting:

```
a = '{:.{}{}}'.format(1.12345111, x, 'f')  # -> 1.12345

a = '{:.{}{}}'.format(1.12345111, x, '%')  # -> 112.34511%

a = '{:.{}}'.format(1.12345111, '{}{}'.format(x, 'f'))  # -> 112.34511%
```

Finally, If you are using Python3.6, see the excellent [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) answer by [@m_____z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928643/6162307).

Comment: The code you gave worked like a charm! I would like to thank you and the other members here for your quick and helpful responses. Just to clarify, the {0} stands for the the x variable.. it is its position. that part i understand. What about the beginning 1: ? What does that stand for in this code? that it takes two arguments (x, 1.12345111) in the format function??

Comment: Both the `0` and the `1` are indexes in the tuple passed to `.format()`. So in this case, `0` *points to* `x` and `1` *to* `1.12345111`. Think of it as doing `(x, 1.12345111)[0]`.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the last part. Now I got it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I believe that last part([@m_____z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928643/3124746)) should be only in @m_____z's answer. Because answered time is the same, and you just added his/her answer to your's.

Comment: @vishes_shell you are absolutely correct, edited.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're using Python 3.6, you could simply do the following:

```
x = 5
my_array[1, 0] = f'{a:.{x}f}'
```

Comment: A little late reply (sorry), anyway.. I wanted to try alternative methods. Your example was a good and new way to do it. It works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Two ways this can be accomplished. Either by using str.format() or by using %

Where `a` is the number you're trying to print and `x` is the number of decimal places we can do:

str.format:

```
'{:.{dec_places}f}'.format(a, dec_places=x)
```

%:

```
'%.*f' % (x, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=5
f='{0:.'+str(x)+'f}'
my_array[1, 0] = f.format(a)
```